# Is Japanese democracy an isolated example?

Tags: japan, democracy

There is something peculiar about the current [Japanese political system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Japan#Post-war_political_developments_in_Japan): it is a democratic system which was imposed upon Japan by an invading foreign country (USA, in this case) which remained as a democracy even after the departure of the invasion forces. Furthermore (unlike, say, West Germany after the end of World War II), in the past Japan had only known a very limited form of democracy (for instance, little more than 1% of the population could vote for the parliament).

So, my question is:

> Is there any other example in history (other than Japan) of a country which had never been a democracy before, or which had only known a very limited form of democracy, and which became one because a foreign country (or several foreign countries) imposed democracy on them, and which remained a democracy long after the invading country (or countries) has left?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129325/discussion-on-question-by-jose-carlos-santos-is-japanese-democracy-an-isolated-e).

Answer (score 3):

Your question has several criteria:

1. Country is invaded by a foreign power
2. A "democratic" system is imposed upon the people who live there by the foreign power
3. After the foreign power leaves a "democracy" remains.

Examples of this are legion. Here are a non-complete list of countries that experienced this:

- Canada
- India
- Pakistan
- Bangladesh
- Maylasia
- South Korea
- Botswana
- Mauritius
- Cape Verde
- Senegal
- Ghana
- Nigeria
- Sao Tome and Principe
- Namibia
- South Africa
- Benin
- Jamaica
- Germany
- Italy

There are probably a lot more. I put democracy in quotes because it's not really an objectively definable thing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129324/discussion-on-answer-by-axsvl77-is-japanese-democracy-an-isolated-example).

Comment: This answer explicitely ignores the OPs constraints. It seems you missed: "a country which had never been a democracy before"

Comment: @nvoigt Please read the "moved to chat" comments.